# How to update customer address in netSuite form PHP Toolkit

Tags: netsuite, php-toolkit

Hi i am working in **netSuite and PHP Toolkit**. I want to update customer address how can i load load customer and update address. This is the customer object but how can i load specific customer for it.

```
$customer = new Customer();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I would bother with the PHP Toolkit.  I did look at it and went down the RESTlet route.  Much cleaner and you're not loading that library every time you make a call.